# grunt serve opens a page that indcates "a communication error occured"

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-connect

When i launch grunt serve command, a page opens and a message is written :
A communication error occurred: ""

I must type my ip-address:9000 to see my app because localhost:9000 is not working.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually it was because of the cache of my browser

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but could you verify if in the `Grunfile.js` you have this on line 69 - 72 :

```
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729
```

You must have the 'localhost' in the hostname if you're running your server on local.

Hope it will help.